# Powerpivot function not available to office 2010

Tags: powerpivot

My office 2010 does not have some of the function of Powerpivot (EVALUATE, SUMMARIZE Etc.). Is this not available to office 2010?

Answer (score 0):

EVALUATE is not a function. SUMMARIZE() is available in the most  recent version of Power Pivot for Excel 2010.

It sounds like you've got the SQL Server 2008R2 version of Power Pivot installed. You want the SQL Server 2012 SP1 version, [available here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29074).

Comment: Thanks...I've been searching for this answer but can't find